# Using groupBy on a set of keywords in Javascript (or Mixpanel JQL)

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I am new to Javascript (which is used for Mixpanel's JQL language).

I have written the following Javascript / JQL code to filter down a result and group it by any SearchQuery's containing `automotive`.

It works great, but what I'd actually like is to group by the keywords I'm querying (ex: `automotive`), and see the associated volume of results. Is it possible to adjust the script so that it returns the keyword being queried and the volume of results that match that keyword?

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

SearchQuery | Volume

automotive transmission | 10

automotive lighting | 2

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

automotive | 12

(...other keywords | other volumes....)

**CODE**

```
function main() {
  return Events({
    from_date: '2019-07-01',
    to_date:   '2019-07-31'
  })
.filter(function(event) { 
    return event.name == "Search"
    && event.properties.SearchQuery
    })
  .groupBy(["properties.SearchQuery"], mixpanel.reducer.count())
  .filter(function(event){
    return event.key[0].toLowerCase().search(/\bautomotive\b/)>-1
    })
}
```

Comment: You have confused jQuery with something else. jQuery is primarily a dom manipulation library

Comment: Ahh, should it be just javascript then?